# Any electric insulation material that is great heat conductor even 300°C?

Tags: insulation, heater

Is there any good electric insulation material or tape that is also great heat conductor even 300°C and above. I wish to wrap nichrome wires with this material in creating a water cup heater.
Thanks.

Comment: Diamond, but maybe not what you’re looking for.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to use a diamond for my problem.

Comment: why are none of the existing https://lmgtfy.app/?q=cup+immersion+heater designs acceptable?

Comment: Carve a cup out of a stone

Comment: Immerse PTFE insulated wire into the water, and keep the power density low enough that the metal core doesn't exceed 200 C or so.

Comment: Why does it have to be a 'great' heat conductor?

Comment: Not so great will do, as long it heats the water in the container

Comment: Why bother with insulation? Seriously, why insulate? And why 300 degC?

Comment: You're looking at ceramics. There are machinable ones, or you might look at stove repair cement to mould your own, though I can't vouch for its durability.

Comment: Micca can be hard to wrap anything round and small like a soldering element

Comment: Why not use a few power resistors instead of trying to insulate your own wire like it's the 19th century?

Comment: Do you need to use a single material? Can you use a thin layer of electrical insulation, and a thicker layer of thermally conductive material?

Comment: Unless you have a specific use case, you can easily buy immersion heaters for "heating a cup of water". Even in food grade. Why do you need to re-invent the water cup heater?

Answer (score 2):

At that temperature, you're going to need some sort of ceramic material, either powdered or solid.

But why does a "water cup heater" need to get so hot? Polyimide tape (a.k.a. Kapton tape) will get you up to 260 °C or so.

Some types of [Sil-Pad](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/99609.pdf) can be used up to 200  °C.

Comment: The water itself wont even reach 90C before the thermostat will cut off. The nichrome itself gets far very hot at 4A 12V, I had checked.

Comment: I bet you checked the temperature of the nichrome wire in the air. It won't get nearly so hot when it's in water.

Comment: I don't wish to dip anything in the water. Need to heat up water in a container wrapped by nichrome. that is also where I need insulation for electricity and conductivity for heat.

Answer (score 2):

Use **MICA SHEET**, it was initially used in soldering iron to conduct heat from coil to soldering iron metal body, at the same time insulating electrically. It can easily work till 600degC and it has a very high electrical resistance in the order of several hundred MegaOhm.

Comment: Can you explain how to wrap mica sheets around a wire?

Comment: Flexible mica tape comes in various sizes, that can be used to wrap around a wire.